# How to revert some changes to files in my working copy before doing commit

Tags: git

I have edited myfile, but I realized I do want some of the changes I did to it, while I want to discard some others. I'm looking for the magic command in the lines of

```
git diff --edit myfile
```

where `--edit` would open a vimdiff (or other editor) with myfile on my working copy on one side, and with myfile on HEAD on the other side.
Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git difftool --tool=$YOUR_FAVORITE_DIFF_TOOL <filename>`

You can do `git difftool --help` to see all supported difftools.

Answer (score 1):

I like using

```
git commit --patch
```

This allows you to pick and choose which sections you want to add, and then once you've committed, you can

```
git checkout -- [files]
```

or

```
git reset --hard
```

(be careful with the git reset hard, make sure everything was properly committed)

Comment: Thanks Kevin, thats what I was going for :)

Comment: This seems to be useful though I guess I need more git yoga first to try it. Thanks!